# Unity "Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`3' is declared in multiple referenced assemblies". VERSION: 2020.3.17f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, assemblies

One day I open my project and now have 50 errors from unity built in packages saying that System.ValueTuple is defined in multiple places. Visual Studio is finding any problems, and my many google searches have had no luck. I have tried nuGet, and removing assembly references but the problem persists.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btGME.png)

I opened the project one day and it surprisingly asked me to enter safe mode. It suddenly had all these errors that weren't there previously. Visual Studio doesn't say there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

just ended up reverting github commit, then undoing the revert and it worked fine